# Read QML element size defined by anchors.fill: parent

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qml

I'm writing a [QML extension](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-extending-tutorial-index.html) plugin and I'm looking for a way to access the size of the element I've just implemented.

Right now the new element (named `CustomElement`) can be created with any size the user wants to by defining it's **width** and **height** values, so on a QML file the user can do:

```
CustomElement 
{
     id: my_elem
     width: 800
     height: 600
}
```

But **I would like to be able to retrieve the size information when the user configures the size through an `anchor`**, like this:

```
Rectangle
{
    width: 800
    height: 600

    CustomElement 
    {
        id: my_elem
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to access `anchors` information.

The plugin class is defined as:

```
class CustomElement: public QDeclarativeItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //Q_PROPERTY() stuff
public:
    // ...
};
```

In the constructor of the plugin, I set `QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents` to false:

```
CustomElement::CustomElement(QDeclarativeItem* parent)
: QDeclarativeItem(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "CustomElement::CustomElement parent is:" << parent;

    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents, false);
}
```

After adding the debug, I noticed that the `parent` is `0`, which explains why I'm not able to retrieve useful information with `boundingRect()` and others methods. Apparently, the problem is that my plugin has no parent. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**.

Reading *[When is the parent set?](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/4406)* helped me to find what I needed to do. This plugin is a graphical component (i.e. has a visual interface) meaning it will be draw on screen at some point. When Qt finishes loading your component, it calls a method named `componentComplete()` to notify you of so.

All I had to do was add this method to my class definition as a public method:

```
virtual void componentComplete();
```

and implement it as:

```
void CustomElement::componentComplete()
{
    Q_D(CustomElement);    

    // Call superclass method to set CustomElement() parent
    QDeclarativeItem::componentComplete();   
}
```

Calling the method of the superclass seems to set the parent of my plugin, and this gives me access to the information set by `anchors.fill: parent`.

Then all I had to do retrieve this information was:

```
Q_Q(Video);
qDebug() << "CustomElement::play: widget size is " << q->width() << "x" << q->height();
```

Comment: You just put an end to a three days search !! Which I could upvote ten times

Comment: Hmm it still does not work for me. What are Q_D and Q_Q. If I call Q_D on my class name I get a comiler Error. Could you post a complete example ?