# How to wait layout sistem to determine item's size when exposing QML item to C++?

Tags: c++, qml, rendering, off-screen, qquickitem

I am working on a spesific case about taking images from a running QML application.

I do that by rendering QQuickItems(which is exposed from qml) on a off-screen window to grab their images.

Exposing & passing part: (this can be done in main.cpp)

```
    QQuickItem* item = m_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("rectObject");
    QmlOffScreenRenderer renderer(item);
```

If I define a height and a width for a qml item then I can access exposed item sizes from it's width() and height() method:

#In Qml:

```
Rectangle {
  objectName: "rectObject"
  width: 100
  height: 100
}
```

#In C++:

```
m_item->height(); -> gives 100
m_item->width();  -> gives 100
```

###But...

If I set anchors instead of height property like:

#In Qml:

```
Rectangle {
  objectName: "rectObject"

  anchors {
    top: parent.top
    bottom: parent.bottom
    right: parent.left

  width: 100
}
```

#In C++:

```
m_item->height(); -> gives 0
m_item->width();  -> gives 100
```

I know that when a QML item exposed to C++, the item's size is not immediately available in C++. This is because the size of a QML item is determined by the layout system, which runs asynchronously. So, how can I wait the exposed Qml item polished(so I can set window size and opengl frame buffer size to it) to render it on my new window to capture an image?

I would be very greatful if you could share your opinion on that :)

### Edit

- Removed unneeded code blocks

### What I've tried:

- I have called polish() method of QQuickItem to force it to be polished in my off-screen window before rendering process but it does not seem to work, maybe the order the code is wrong somehow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272998/read-qml-element-size-defined-by-anchors-fill-parent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read QML element size defined by anchors.fill: parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272998/read-qml-element-size-defined-by-anchors-fill-parent)